# May I take advantage of the existence of a tomcat server for new .war application or should I have a new web server?

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Is it right to use a tomcat app server from another application to deploy my new .WAR which is basically an REST client from the tomcat's owner application?

The scenario is like:

Application A - which is very monolithic has a tomcat apps server installed for itself to work. They also may have customized the tomcat, and let's image the tomcat as a dependency for application A to work.

I need a REST client to work with application A, let's call app B.

should I separate app B it from the A tomcat's application?

What are the best practices?

I am not sure if is a good practice to just take advantage from an existing tomcat, or the most correct way, and also to avoid dependency problem...

Comment: There is a lot about your question that needs to be clarified before anyone can answer properly.  However, 1) it is neither "good practice" or "bad practice" to deploy multiple webapps in a Tomcat server, and 2) two WARs is a Tomcat server doesn't create any direct dependencies between them.

Comment: One thing that doesn't make sense to me is this: "my new .WAR which is basically an REST client from the tomcat's owner application". What does "the tomcat's owner application" mean? What is the point of deploying an REST API client as a WAR file?  (Or is it **actually** a web service that uses the client code?)

Comment: Finally, since you are asking for so called "Best Practices", this is inherently an Opinion question.  Read [No Best Practices!](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164) to understand why.  You should stop asking and talking about so called "best practice" because ... basically ... it doesn't really exist in the IT world.  All situations are different and no solutions or technical strategies are suitable for all of them.  You need to weigh up the pros and cons of each technical decision in its specific context.

Comment: Sure. The whole purpose of Tomcat and indeed all servlet  containers is to host multiple applications.

Comment: Answering @StephenC, Tomcat owner application is the application that installed the tomcat for itself to work properly, and this application may have actually customized the tomcat.

Comment: @StephenC I edited the question, maybe is clear now?

Comment: Well ... if you don't know what those customizations are / may be, then there is a risk that your app may interfere with those customizations ... somehow.  But we can't quantify those risks for you.  Why not ask the vendor of the "owner application" for advice?

Comment: Yes the question is clearer.  But the still don't think that it is answerable.  It is too high level.  And you are still asking for opinions ... which is another reason to close it.

Comment: that's exactly, the thing is, I interprete that deploying the application B into tomcats/webapps that only exists because application A uses tomcat, not because application A is deployed in a tomcat is a wrong move... you see the same?

Comment: I am not going to give you my opinion on that.  What is my opinion worth?  How do you know that?  What about the next guy who gives an opinion?

Comment: Ok dude you are free to close this website :)